# How to format string in java SE7?

Tags: java, string, format

From java tutorial:

```
 System.out.format("%s: %s"
            + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
            this.name, bower.getName());
```

But in java SE7 there are not such method.
Which method I should use?
Thanks.

Comment: there is the very class in java 7, did you even bother to check the API ??http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `String.format` or `System.out.printf`.

```
System.out.printf("%s: %s"
    + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
    this.name, bower.getName());
```

`String.format` returns the result in a `String`; `System.out.printf` prints the result to the console.

(And jbx is also correct: why do you say that there's no such method in Java SE 7?).

Comment: although a good alternative,System.out.format() is in java 7, i can see it in the API:

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is:

System.out is of type PrintStream, which has [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

If you don't want to output it but just store it in a string, `String` also offers the same method [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)